# jquery value from .attr not correct in IE

Tags: php, jquery, substr

For one of my javascript functions I'm using jqueries .attr method to retrieve an href value from my pagination value.  The call is simply

```
$(".pager").click(function(){
    var start = $(this).attr('href');
    alert("START: " + start);
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<a href="#10" class="pager"><span class="page_no">2</span></a>
<a href="#20" class="pager"><span class="page_no">3</span></a>
...
```

In both FF and Chrome I see the Start value as 10 (clicking on the first href).
In IE it returns the entire HTML (e.g.)

```
mysite/search_results.php#10
```

I even tried using substring like so:

```
var start = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
```

but this also returned the URL less the first charcter in my address:

```
ysite/search_results.php#10
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: off the top of my head, don't use href. Instead use a data- attribute or jQuery's own data property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    var start = $(this).attr('href').slice($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#')+1));
} else {
    var start = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

This code isn't tested or exact, but you get the gist - if you're in IE, get the position of the '#' and get a substring from there to the end, else use the whole value of href.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! It drives me crazy how difficult IE can be sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".pager").click(function(){
    var hashSplit = this.href.split('#');
    var start = hashSplit[hashSplit.length -1];
    alert("START: " + start);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/PCJEF/

I have tested and it works in IE

Answer (score 0):

IE is dumb, do this:

```
var start = $(this).attr('href').replace(document.location.pathname,'');
```

Comment: close, but it's just removing search_results.php so the url now looks like this: mysite/#10

Comment: Odd, `document.location.pathname` should return everything after the document root.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this might be something to do with javascripts default behavior when returning urls (similar to image src, return the full path). You can try using the javascript split method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp on # and then getting the value. This should return the 10,20 as well in Chrome and FF as it will split on the # and not include it. The second part should then always be the number:

```
   var s = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
   alert(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that though the attr method is meant to reduce diffrences among browsers, it does not always, as JQuery's site says:

> Cross-browser consistency: The values of some attributes are reported inconsistently across browsers, and even across versions of a single browser. The .attr() method **reduces** such inconsistencies.

so this only reduces that chance; it does not eliminate it.

So, I think the only way I can see to fix it is to use someones answer looks like TommyBs' answer is promising using this code:

```
 var s = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
```

Here is a forum with solutions:
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/javascript-15/jquery-href-value-problem-665692.html